# Searching from multiple models (jquery autocomplete)

Tags: python, django

I'm using [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) and following `view` to display list of objects in `inputfiled`. It worked.

```
#views
m = M.objects.filter(title__istartswith=q)
results = [ x.title for x in m ]
json = simplejson.dumps(results)
return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/json")
```

This view searching objects from `one model`. What should I have to do If I've to search from another model too? Like

```
  He (From M Model)
  hel (From M Model)
# hell (From P Model)
```

So also I want to search from `P Model`. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add two lists like that:

```
m1 = M1.objects.filter(title__istartswith=q)
m2 = M2.objects.filter(title__istartswith=q)
results = [x.title for x in m1] + [x.title for x in m2]
```

Don't forget to limit results somehow.

Comment: Do you return data in correct format that autocomplete understands?